# How to join two beams rigidly?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, modeling, abaqus

Hi I am making a beam model using Abaqus. There are two beams created. I wanted to join two beams rigidly in the connection to transfer moments between beams. However, I do not know what connector or constraint should be used to complete such a task.

Here is the model I used, I created chain wire at the same point and created the following as a connector section to be assigned to this wire set. However, it does not work and give error:"Node set assembly_Part-1_Part-refpt_ has no members and will be ignored. Nodes defined in this set may have been deleted because they were not connected to any elements.".
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please help to solve this connection problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Just define the two beams with a common node - exactly the same way as you "rigidly join" any other finite elements! Things only get more complicated if you *don't* want a fully rigid connection.